# ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack (python lists)

Tags: python

I'm learning python from Google code class. I'm trying out the exercises.

```
def front_x(words):
  x_list, ord_list = []
  for word in words:
    if word[0] == 'x':
      x_list.append(word)
    else:
      ord_list.append(word)
  return sorted(x_list) + sorted(ord_list)
```

I believe the error is thrown because of initializing two empty lists on a single line. If if initialize them on separate lines, no more errors occur. Is this the reason?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You are trying to use tuple assignment:

```
x_list, ord_list = []
```

you probably meant to use multiple assignment:

```
x_list = ord_list = []
```

which will not do what you expect it to; use the following instead:

```
x_list, ord_list = [], []
```

or, best still:

```
x_list = []
ord_list = []
```

When using a comma-separated list of variable names, Python expects there to be a sequence of expressions on the right-hand side that matches the number variables; the following would be legal too:

```
two_lists = ([], [])
x_list, ord_list = two_lists
```

This is called tuple unpacking. If, on the other hand, you tried to use multiple assignment with *one* empty list literal (`x_list = ord_list = []`) then both `x_list` and `ord_list` would be pointing to the *same* list and any changes made through one variable will be visible on the other variable:

```
>>> x_list = ord_list = []
>>> x_list.append(1)
>>> x_list
[1]
>>> ord_list
[1]
```

Better keep things crystal clear and use two *separate* assignments, giving each variable their own empty list.

Comment: +1 @Martijn Pieters this helped. Could you elaborate on why you ranked the different approaches the way you did. Trying to learn some best practice on this.

Comment: @musked: not sure what you mean. At best I have two approaches named, one using tuple assignment, and one using two separate assignments. I'd use the latter because it is more explicit, readability matters.

Comment: yeah that is exactly what I meant so you ranked according to readability, I thought there might be something I missed out on.

Answer (score 5):

Change the line

```
x_list, ord_list = []

to

x_list, ord_list = [], []
```

Comment: This would be the simplest equivalent of what I want to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

return type of function  does not match with values expected in function...

check the number of variables returned from function and variables you are expecting